# How to find all loaded forms in a .net compact framework Winform application?

Tags: c#

I have a Winform application which contains 10 forms.

I want to find out how many forms are loaded and then I want to call a method

on these loaded forms.

How can I do it ?

Please give me some idea .....

Answer (score 3):

`Application.OpenForms` for Windows Forms only. For Compact Framework you need to handle it your own. check this link

http://dandohotaru.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/caching-opened-forms-in-net-compact.html