# close a windows form from another windows form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, compact-framework

I am working windows mobile application in compact framework 3.5.I want to close a windows form from another windows form.

I tried like below,

```
Book newform = (Book)Application.OpenForms["Book"];
newform.Close();
```

I am getting this error "`'System.Windows.Forms.Application' does not contain a definition for 'OpenForms'`".I checked  in Application form and this `OpenForms` is not available.May i know the equivalent fix of  `OpenForms`  in compact framework or please provide me an alternative solution.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compact Framework - get all open forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278606/compact-framework-get-all-open-forms)

Comment: See link above: TL;DR: there is no such feature, you'll have to track your forms manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent.  The Compact Framework is compact because it doesn't include a lot of stuff that isn't needed.  If you need to access a form later then keep a reference to it when you create it, which is what you should generally be doing in an application targeted at the full Framework anyway.

You don't necessarily have to create a class that tracks all forms, as is done in the link provided by Blogbeard.  If this is just a one-off then just keep that one reference.  If you need to do it lots for various forms, then a centralised form manager may be a better option.